# How can I split a two part padded string into two variables with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string, `userName`, that looks something like this:

```
var userName = "CityOfLiverpool-----joesmith";
var userName = "Hull----------------janesmith";
```

The first part of `userName` is the Account: `"CityOfLiverpool"`

The second part of `userName` is the User: `"joesmith"`

The Account is always a maximum of 20 characters and is padded to the right with hyphens.

How can I extract the Account and the User?

Comment: Use a regexp with capture groups.

Comment: `String.prototype.split()` accepts a regular expression - `"foo----bar".split(/-+/)` -> `["foo", "bar"]`

Comment: @Samantha J: Account and User part can have - ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a regexp with capture groups for the two parts that are separated by hyphens.

```
var match = userName.match(/^([^-]+)-+(.*)$/);
var firstName = match[1];
var lastName = match[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way:

```
var parts = userName.split('-');
var firstPart = parts[0];
var lastPart = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the Account and User with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
userName.match(/^([^-]{1,20})-*(.*)$/)
```

The `^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end. `[^-]` matches any character that is not a hyphen, and `[^-]{1,20}` matches anywhere between 1 and 20 such characters. `-*` matches zero or more hyphens. `.*` matches zero or more characters of any kind.

The whole regular expression breaks down as follows:

```
^             start of string
([^-]{1,20})  1 to 20 characters, each of which is not a hyphen
-*            zero or more hyphens
(.*)          zero or more characters of any kind
$             end of string
```

After doing

```
match = userName.match(/^([^-]{1,20})-*(.*)$/)
```

you can look up the first parenthesized group as `match[1]` and the second parenthesized group as `match[2]`.

```js
var userName = "Hull----------------janesmith";

var match = userName.match(/^([^-]{1,20})-*(.*)$/),
    account = match[1],
    user = match[2];
document.write('account = "'+account+'"<br />user = "'+user+'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of this solutions will not work if the user name contains hyphens or if the account is 20 characters long.
This is an alternative based on the fact that the account is always 20 characters:

```
var account = userName.substr(0,20).replace(/-+$/, "");
var name = userName.substr(20, userName.length-20);
```